# Is it bad practice to create and shutdown services during runtime?

Tags: ros, services, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying to connect my robot to a webserver using a node communication node.
This node creates the service "/get_webdata" when the connection is established and authenticated. When the connection is lost, the service is destroyed again.
This allows me to use wait_for_service in other nodes, which is pretty useful for waiting without ugly sleep-loops.

So my question is: is this a common ros practice to use:

```
webdata = rospy.Service("/get/webdata", Webdata, self.web_cb)
```

and

```
webdata.shutdown("Connection lost")
```

to signal other nodes if the connection is up?
I didn't read anywhere that it's bad practice, but it feels like I'm abusing this feature.
Would it be a better solution to keep the service running all the time and instead return a status variable, indicating that the connection is unavailable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198134/is-it-bad-practice-to-create-and-shutdown-services-during-runtime?/) by [didi2002](https://answers.ros.org/users/20911/didi2002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi didi2002!

if you are providing some sort of feedback or action after the service is called I don't see any problem. However, if the only reason why the service is online is to be able to ask if service "X" is available, then maybe a true/false parameter in the parameter server may be enough. The alternative solution that you are proposing is also valid.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [didi2002](https://answers.ros.org/users/20911/didi2002/) on 2014-11-24**:
The ros-service is also used by the other nodes, not only for checking if the connection is up.
I like the idea of using the parameter server, but I want to avoid polling and sleeping because that introduced quite a delay.

Thanks for your reply!